# How to save product position in category programatically in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, category, position

I want to save the product position based on the category. I have checked and no help available related to this.

So, please help me in saving product position based on category programmatically in Magento.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your question, try adding an example

Comment: yes, needed more info to understand the exact outcomes

Comment: What version Magento you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save product position in category programmatically in magento, Use below code:

```
$categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds(); 
$api = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category_api');
foreach ($categoryIds as $categoryId) {
    $api->assignProduct($categoryId, $productId, $productPosition);
}
```

**Note:** if you are saving product data then use this code after `$_product->save()`;